# How to deploy from GitHub to server via SSH

Tags: github-actions

I have a little security concern - and maybe someone could point me in the right direction:

I have a website, which is tested via GitHub action every push.
Now I want to deploy it too on every successful push. Therefore, I need to push the built and tested site via SSH to my server.

To do that, I would need to put my SSH key into the GitHub action script.
Would that make any sense?

My concern is that then there is a SSH key laying around for everyone who has access to the GitHub action file and can login to the server :/
That is probably not what it is meant to be like or is it?

Comment: "github actions secrets" -> https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a dedicate SSH key reserved just for that usage: do not reuse a key you are already using locally.

Second, that private SSH key, created for this, should not have a passphrase (should not be encrypted)

Third, you can [register it as a secret](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#creating-encrypted-secrets-for-a-repository)

Forth, make sure the public key is set in your target server `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, assuming your server is reachable from internet, allowing the GitHub remote runner to reach it, on port 22.

Comment: @HannesF Great, well done!